# bash script - why does it not open the first file?

Tags: bash, file

I want to do something with text from two files simultaneously.

```
fname3=XX1.txt fname2=XX2.txt


while read -r -u3 line1; read -r -u4 line2; do
    echo "$line1:$line2";
done 3< "$fname3" 4< "$fname2"
```

The output shows always ":(text)", I expect it to output "(text):(text)".
The files are large, does it matter?

Comment: I duplicated bash script to another file. The first file works, but the second file does not work, does the copying of the script matter? The files are really big...

Comment: Are you looking for `paste -d: XX1.txt XX2.txt`?

Comment: No, I am going to save text from both files into two separate values in a sqlite file. The small files do work, but not the large files.

Comment: Copying the script only matters if the copy is incorrect.  Are the two files the same?  (Not by inspection: compute an md5sum or do a diff.)

Comment: @william No. They contains different texts, and had different amount lines. I fixed it so they have same amount of lines. How do I do a diff?

Comment: Is your script being run as `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine as posted for any size of file. Here's a complete, self-contained script that demos it for million line files:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "foo%s\n" {1..1000000} > XX1.txt
printf "bar%s\n" {1..1000000} > XX2.txt

fname3=XX1.txt fname2=XX2.txt

while read -r -u3 line1; read -r -u4 line2; do
    echo "$line1:$line2";
done 3< "$fname3" 4< "$fname2"
```

The output is:

```
foo1:bar1
foo2:bar2
...
foo999999:bar999999
foo1000000:bar1000000
```

If the first file is shorter than the second, the last remaining lines will be `:line` until the second file is entirely read. If the second file is shorter, the script will stop when it's done and ignore the rest of the first file.

To stop when any file runs out of lines, use `&&` instead of `;` to separate the read statements. To read until both files are out of lines, use `||`.

Comment: I did, and updated the example to debunk your theory about large files as well. Perhaps you'd like to provide your own test case that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Ah, it was 10 lines less in the first file than the second file. However I still get same output. I also get error in between output that says "Error: near "s": syntax error" It is a sqlite error, but what does this error mean?

Comment: +1 for self-contained demo solution (and a good solution to boot)!. Good luck to all.

Comment: If sqlite outputs that, it means that there was a syntax error near the token "s". This is the kind of thing that typically happens if you e.g. write `select foo from bar where bar s null` (instead of "is null"). It's kind of outside the scope this question though.

Comment: @that But I don't have such a line in my bash script, so I don't understand why I do get this error message. However, I still can't read from two files line by line at the same time. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Interesting, I changed echo "$line1:$line2" to echo "$line2:$line1" and it showed only the text after : and it reads from correct file as expected. Why is it not possible to echo the text before :?

Comment: Try focusing on one thing at a time. Manually create two files, rather than getting sqllite involved. Then try to read from both using the tips in this answer. If you can't get it working, you can post a new question with your two exact input files, your complete, self contained line reading code, your full expected output, and the actual output of the code you post (i.e. don't write the full program, then copy only parts of the code and say there's something wrong with it).

Comment: @that Well, when I echo each line separately, they did output as expected and every line from both files were actually written into sqlite despite error message. I guess bash script couldn't echo a line from each of the two (large) files at the same time. So I accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is concatenate corresponding lines, use `paste`:

```
paste -d : $fname3" "$fname2"
```

Comment: please read my comments under my question. It is not concatenating I want to and besides I cant read line by line from two files at the same time.